# SocketIO emit with callback fails while upgrading 0.9.16 to 1.3.5

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, upgrade

In 0.9.16, I use socket.emit with callback so that the chat server return some data and I can handle the result as per the acknowledgement. But after the upgrade to 1.3.5 I've found a error in console like this

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined.

I've done something like this,

**From web**

```
socket.emit('userToUser', { 'usename': 'John',
'message': 'hi'
}, function(callback){
//callback handled
});
```

**Chat Server**

```
socket.on('userToUser', function(content, callback){
//do something
if(callback) return callback({'result':'success', 'messageid':content.messageid, 'chatid':content.chatid});
});
```

When I removed the callback from client side, there is no error.
So I believe there will be some changes to be done in the callback.

***I'm getting the acknowledgement and the chat is working properly, but my concern is about the console error which leads to socketio.js***

```
Socket.prototype.onack = function(packet){
  debug('calling ack %s with %j', packet.id, packet.data);
  var fn = this.acks[packet.id];
  fn.apply(this, packet.data);
  delete this.acks[packet.id];
};
```

Guys, please help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I've fixed the issue. It was a mistake in my code , I've done multiple callbacks in the chat server.
like this:

```
socket.on('userToUser', function(content, callback){

  mysql.insertChat(content, function(err, data){
      return callback({'result':'1'})   //first callback
  })  
  sendToUser(content, function(errm successData){
      return callback({'result':'success','chatid':content.chatid});
      //second callback ->wrong
  })

});
```

> In the previous versions it was a warning, now its an error !! That's it. **So please avoid multiple callbacks**

Please have a look at this and might be useful for every nodejs developer:
http://www.toptal.com/nodejs/top-10-common-nodejs-developer-mistakes/#remote-developer-job

Thanks guys for upvoting !

Comment: Just an FYI it worked before because of a memory leak in Socket.IO 0.9.x - The handlers were never cleaned up correctly (and thus leaking memory and actually making your server/client vulnerable for attacks) which allowed you to continuously call the callback.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: <s>This is not how callbacks work with socket.io v1.3.5. In fact, the emit function does not accept any callbacks at all.</s>

I'm guessing you want to send an acknowledgement to the *sending node* that its message has been received. To accomplish that, you need to make another `socket.emit` call from the server (on the server, socket variable represents the *connection to a specific node* in the network whereas on the client, the socket variable represents the *connection to the server*). Consequently, on the client, you need to handle the acknowledgement with a `socket.on` which is where you'll put your callback.

To broadcast the acknowledgement to ALL nodes in the network, you should use `io.emit`.

Code sample for a chat application using socket.io is available [here](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/).

Comment: I think you are wrong, because socketio support callback, see this socket.io/docs/#sending-and-getting-data-(acknowledgements)